# Sublime regex replace merging replace text with capture group

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, replace

Pretty simple problem just never encountered it before.

Say I'm replacing address information in a set of test data I have with different values. Simple stuff except that in one case I have a capture group that is to be followed directly after by a number. e.g.

```
Regex - \d*(/?)\d (.*)
Text -  123 Main Street [should become] 72 Main Street
        1/3 Main Street [should become] 7/2 Main Street
Replace - 7$1B $2  <- works fine
          7$12 $2  <- tries to replace with group $12 rather than $1
```

Anyone know how to define these as separate without introducing any whitespace or other characters?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can try other substitutions like `${1}` instead of `$1`

[Substitutions in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx) should help you..

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to replace `@since(.*)NEXT` with `@since$11.0.0` and that wasn't working, but `@since${1}1.0.0` did.

Comment: Thanks @Anirudha, just tried this successfully in Sublime Text.